# AC Decade Sweep LTSPICE Error

Tags: ac, simulation, ltspice

The output plot for Vo/(Vg) is not outputting a smooth curve. I chose a decade sweep with starting frequency 1 Hz and end frequency of 10 GHz. Why is the plot not smooth? I am pretty sure I built the circuit correctly.

[image: schematic]

This is the simulation at 10 points/decade.
[image: simulation output]

Simulation at 1000 points/dec.
[image: Output at 1000 points/dec]

Comment: With 10 points/dec you'll hardly get any information. Increase it to at least 100, if not 1k. `.AC` simulations come cheap and fast, no need to get "scroogey". Also, be careful how you take the references for votages.

Comment: What's wrong with how I take the references for voltages? Also I tried increasing the points/dec, but now the output is even worse. It is not a curve at all.

Comment: I didn't say it's wrong, just to take care. For example you might need to reference a voltage between various nodes, as opposed to the ground. I don't know if that's the case, that is up to you to know.

Comment: Also up to you is what you're building, for example I see 3 caps there and all of them are `1F`, are you sure about them? Are you sure you have to reference the voltage `V(vg1)` to ground, as opposed to, say, `V(vd1)` (and thus `V(vg1,vd1)`)? Or `V(sig)`?

Comment: The capacitor values are as such so they are a DC block, and a small signal short. Also I am not sure how to reference voltages to other voltages in a simulation. Do you mean subtract the potentials?

Comment: Verify your Cap units of 1 then your DC stability time.